# Getting notified when an article I cited in one of my papers gets retracted

Tags: citations, retraction

Is there any way to get notified (e.g., by email) when an article I cited in one of my papers gets retracted?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could set up a [Google Alert](https://www.google.com/alerts) or set up a similar event handler at http://www.changedetection.com/.

I have tried both of these services.  Once in a while they both catch the same thing, but for the most part they complement each other.